# Automatically renaming and copying files that are put into a given directory

Tags: powershell, copy, watch, file-rename

I'm trying to "watch" a folder via Powershell Script, that copies files, that are getting put into the folder into another folder and adds a prefix to the name of the file.

Via some researching, i have got this:

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\Raphael\Desktop\Desktop\ITC\Test"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                ###Rename-Item $path -NewName { "Prefix_" + $_.Name }
                Copy-Item $path -Destination "C:\Users\Raphael\Desktop\Desktop\ITC\Test\testdestination" -Force -Verbose
              }
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    ###Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    ###Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
    ###Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

With the "Rename-Item" part commented out, it successfully creates a copy into the second folder.
But I cant get the renaming part correct. When not commented out, nothing happens, not even the copying. I have tried using

```
$path | Rename-Item $path -NewName { "Prefix_" + $_.Name }
```

to select the file im "watching" and then rename it, but that brings 2 problems:

1: the file gets renamed to "Prefix_ " and nothing after that

2: the Copy-Item task doesnt even start (im assuming thats because the file was stored in $path with the original name and now "Copy-Item $path ..... " doesnt have anything to copy)

Can anyone help me here? Thanks all in advance!

Comment: When you rename the file, variable `$path` does not change, so after that, the original file will no longer be found, because you have just renamed it.. Change the last two lines in your $action scriptblock into `$target = Join-Path -Path 'C:\Users\Raphael\Desktop\Desktop\ITC\Test\testdestination' -ChildPath ("Prefix_" + $_.Name); Copy-Item $path -Destination $target -Force -Verbose`. (and of course don't forget that the destination path must already exist for the Copy-Item to be able to actually copy something there)

Comment: @Theo
Oh you're right, how did i miss that when i basically said the same thing for my try with
` $path | Rename-Item $path -NewName { "Prefix_" + $_.Name } `

It almost works now, the new file's name is only "Prefix_ " now though, so its losing the old name and also the file-extension

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in my comment I also made a mistake with `$_.Name`.. In the code, there is no `$_` automatic variable representing the file, because you only have `$path` which is a **string** containing the full path and filename.

If you want to rename first and then copy do:

```
$action = { 
    $path       = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType  # not using this?
    $newName    = "Prefix_{0}" -f [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($path)
    # with -PassThru you will receive an object that represents the renamed item.
    $file = Rename-Item -Path $path -NewName $newName -PassThru
    $file | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Users\Raphael\Desktop\Desktop\ITC\Test\testdestination" -Force -Verbose
}
```

If you only want the copy to have a new name, leaving the file in the original location unchanged, do:

```
$action = { 
    $path       = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType # not using this?
    $newName    = "Prefix_{0}" -f [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($path)
    $targetFile = Join-Path -Path 'C:\Users\Raphael\Desktop\Desktop\ITC\Test\testdestination' -ChildPath $newName
    Copy-Item -Path $path -Destination $targetFile -Force -Verbose
}
```

<sup>I always like to use the [-f Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f) when combining strings rather than using `("Prefix_" + [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($path))`, but both will work</sup>